# trying to connect mysql with vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection-string

I've found this at connection strings.com
http://connectionstrings.com/mysql

Do I need to download connector-net from this site: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

I recycled the code that I used in connecting vb.net with ms sql:

```
Imports system.data.sqlclient

idnum = TextBox1.Text
    lname = TextBox2.Text
    fname = TextBox3.Text
    skul = TextBox4.Text

    Using sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=testing;Uid=root;Pwd=mypassword;")

        sqlcon.Open()
        Dim sqlcom As New SqlCommand()
        sqlcom.Connection = sqlcon

        sqlcom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [student](ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SCHOOL) VALUES (@ParameterID, @ParameterLastName, @ParameterFirstName, @ParameterSchool)"

        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterID", TextBox1.Text)
        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterLastName", TextBox2.Text)
        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterFirstName", TextBox3.Text)
        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterSchool", TextBox4.Text)

        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
```

But I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Please help, what solutions would you recommend to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article should get you started:

[The VB.NET-MySQL Tutorial – Part 3](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-3)

The article uses MySQL Connector for .NET...

> MySQL Connector/NET is available for
>   download at
>   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/.
>   Download the version that includes an
>   installer to your local hard-drive and
>   extract the Zip file.
>
> Double-click the installer file to
>   begin the installation process.
>   Perform a complete install to the
>   default directory.

In the code you have:

```
conn = New MySqlConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = "server=" & txtServer.Text & ";" _
& "user id=" & txtUsername.Text & ";" _
& "password=" & txtPassword.Text & ";" _
& "database=in_out"
```

Check this out too:

[Accessing MySQL Database from my VB.NET 2008 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279138/accessing-mysql-database-from-my-vb-net-2008-project)

Comment: Whats the server address default? Is it localhost?

Comment: Yes. It's localhost if you installed MySQL Server on your development machine.